# Kali Linux deletes everything on shutdown

Tags: linux, virtualbox, shutdown

I just downloaded Kali for VirtualBox. And I want to make some changes to it. But i figured out, that when i shut it down, it deletes everything, unless I 'save state'. But when it is in 'saved state' I cannot configurate any settings on it. How do I avoid my settings and files getting deleted everytime I shut the machine down?

Comment: What exactly did you download and what did you do with it? Was it perhaps a LiveCD?

Answer (score 2):

You are not using a persistent Kali install. Kali, by default, loads the OS from media on boot, lets you do what you need to, and then once it is shut off it is gone. This is known as a Live CD or live distribution, kind of like booting a utility from a flash drive to do a memory test. It's only running during the time you specify the system to boot to it and it is like new every time you run it.

Instead, you need to run the installer for Kali (can be done at boot or after boot from a utility) and use this to actually write to the VHD in Virtualbox:

Here's a guide which covers that. Let us know if this is insufficient and I'll include more detailed steps but this should get you on your way.
http://hackercool.com/2013/09/how-to-install-kali-linux-in-virtualbox-step-by-step-guide/

Answer (score 0):

When you shut down, you don't have to reinstall, correct? Make sure you are running the correct installer, I used the graphic installer.

Comment: I don’t see how your VirtualBox problems relate to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I personally didn't use a live cd iso **file**. My issue was that in it was trying to run the ISO each time. After removing the iso from this Storage tab in virtual box settings, it then booted Kali Linux which I had installed on my hard drive.
Hope this helps!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

its simple ..
1. click on shut down option.
2. click on Suspend button.

Now at next time when u open kali linux on virtual, your virtual machine can restore your all previous data.

Comment: A properly installed OS does not require suspension to save files. All evidence points to this being caused by OP not installing Linux and just running it "live".